# Loading Android Players (Multiplayer)

Tags: android

This is for an Android multiplayer game using Google Play Services.
The following code is for getting the current user's friends (in his/her circles on google plus), the problem is when I display the image of the user, it is always the same image. So for example if my friends are: Bob, Dan and John, it will show those names, but the image Urls are all the same...I have no idea what's going on! On one of my devices, it works like it should. But on my Galaxy tab it does this weird thing that I mentioned. I am very confused.
Thanks in advance guys.

```
private void inviteFriend(){
    Games.Players.loadInvitablePlayers(getApiClient(), 3, true).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LoadPlayersResult>(){

        @Override
        public void onResult(LoadPlayersResult result) {

            PlayerBuffer players = result.getPlayers();

            Player friend1 = players.get(0);
            Player friend2 = players.get(1);
            Player friend3 = players.get(2);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_playername);
            tv.setText(friend1.getDisplayName());

            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            (new DownloadImage(iv)).execute(friend1.getIconImageUrl());

            System.out.println("Friend 1 name: " + friend1.getDisplayName());
            System.out.println("Friend 2 name: " + friend2.getDisplayName());
            System.out.println("Friend 3 name: " + friend3.getDisplayName());

            System.out.println("Friend 1 uri: " + friend1.getIconImageUrl());
            System.out.println("Friend 2 uri: " + friend2.getIconImageUrl());
            System.out.println("Friend 3 uri: " + friend3.getIconImageUrl());
            result.release();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you always print the image of `firend1`

```
System.out.println("Friend 1 uri: " + friend1.getIconImageUrl());
System.out.println("Friend 2 uri: " + friend1.getIconImageUrl());
System.out.println("Friend 3 uri: " + friend1.getIconImageUrl());
```

should be

```
System.out.println("Friend 1 uri: " + friend1.getIconImageUrl());
System.out.println("Friend 2 uri: " + friend2.getIconImageUrl());
System.out.println("Friend 3 uri: " + friend3.getIconImageUrl());
```

Comment: My apologize, that was an accident. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Have you checked your actual Code if you have the same mistake there?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely correct in my actual actual code. And like I mentioned, it works fine on my nexus, but not on my tab. That is what I find very unusual.

Comment: that ss strange. try to rebuild your apk and update it to both devices. i think there are only two reasons for this behaviour. either your tab has an older version of the apk where you printed always `friend1.getIconImageUrl()` or the play services are buggy on your tab and therefor result in an invalid result. if the problem is about the play services, you should try to update them somehow and revalidate if the issue still occurs. otherwise i think there might be no proper solution.